# Small axvspan is not visible

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a rather messy graph with matplotlib. The x-axis has different dates. The whole graph shows something like timelines. I have attached an example image.[image: time line standard view]

Do you see the small red bar? I have surrounded that red bar with a green axvspan of the same x-coordinates. But unfortunately it is not visible.

But when I zoom in:
[image: Zoomed in]

Tada, there it is.

Is there any way to make the axvspan visible in the first view?
Something like "Be at least one pixel wide".

Just in case you guys have ideas on how I can change the red box: I can't. I have several unvisible green axvspans in this graph. For a better visualization I have chosen this one over the red box.

Thank you :)

Edit:
Here is some Code which reproduces the behavior:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


# Random data
start_big = pd.Timestamp("2017-03-01 12:00:00").value
end_big = pd.Timestamp("2017-04-22 14:00:00").value
data = list()
colors = list()
for i in range(0, 10):
    start = random.randint(start_big, end_big - 5)
    end = pd.Timestamp(random.randint(start, end_big))
    start = pd.Timestamp(start)
    colors.append("blue")
    data.append((start, end, str(i)))

# the small data with the axvspan
start_small = pd.Timestamp("2017-03-04 12:00:00")
end_small = pd.Timestamp("2017-03-04 12:05:00")
colors[8] = "red"
data[8] = (start_small, end_small, "small")

def dates_to_num(data):
    verts = []
    for index, d in enumerate(data):
        v = [(mdates.date2num(d[0]), index - .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[0]), index + .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[1]), index + .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[1]), index - .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[0]), index - .4)]
        verts.append(v)
    return verts

# plot
bars = PolyCollection(dates_to_num(data))
bars.set_color(colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(bars)
ax.autoscale()

# AXVSPAN:
plt.axvspan(mdates.date2num(start_small), mdates.date2num(end_small), facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)

loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

plt.show()
```

While creating the sample code, I also discovered the cause: the error only appears if I give the very narrow bar a color (No default!).If the narrow bar had the default color it would not be visible because it is too small.
But still I would like to have always the axvspan visible.

Comment: Are you using the latest matplotlib version? I can't reproduce the problem. You might want to add test data and minimal code to create a reproducible example. With older versions you might want to add `axvspan(...., lw=1)` to make sure that the vspan gets a border.  (My test code uses `plt.plot(np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()); plt.axvspan(100, 101, color='r')`)

Comment: Your span is probably less than one pixel and matplotlib conveniently hides it for you.  While this is likely a bug, the workaround is to increase your dpi.  You can also turn snapping on/off.

Comment: @JohanC Unfortunately lw=1 didn't help. I use matplotlib 3.4.2.
I just tried to create minimal code. But unfortunately I cant reproduce the problem... I keep trying and give you an update.

Comment: In fact, when I checked the width of the vertical line, it was only 0.0034. I think this is due to the fact that the x-axis is a time series and is in minutes. This is because the time series is managed by floating point. If you want to see this all the time, you can set DPI=300 or something like that, although the graph will be larger.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for my problem.
not the best one but it works.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


# Random data
start_big = pd.Timestamp("2017-03-01 12:00:00").value
end_big = pd.Timestamp("2017-04-22 14:00:00").value
data = list()
colors = list()
for i in range(0, 10):
    start = random.randint(start_big, end_big - 5)
    end = pd.Timestamp(random.randint(start, end_big))
    start = pd.Timestamp(start)
    colors.append("blue")
    data.append((start, end, str(i)))

# the small data with the axvspan
start_small = pd.Timestamp("2017-03-04 12:00:00")
end_small = pd.Timestamp("2017-03-04 12:05:00")
colors[8] = "red"
data[8] = (start_small, end_small, "small")

def dates_to_num(data):
    verts = []
    for index, d in enumerate(data):
        v = [(mdates.date2num(d[0]), index - .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[0]), index + .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[1]), index + .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[1]), index - .4),
             (mdates.date2num(d[0]), index - .4)]
        verts.append(v)
    return verts

# plot
bars = PolyCollection(dates_to_num(data))
bars.set_color(colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(bars)
ax.autoscale()

# AXVSPAN and AXVLINE:
plt.axvline(mdates.date2num(start_small), color="green", alpha=0.1)
plt.axvspan(mdates.date2num(start_small), mdates.date2num(end_small), facecolor='green', alpha=0.1)
plt.axvline(mdates.date2num(end_small), color="green", alpha=0.1)

loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

plt.show()
```

Now it shows the borders (axvline) in the distance view.